# Can we add a B2C tenant as custom IDP in another B2C tenant?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have two B2C Tenants. 1. B2CTenantA 2. B2CTenantB
Can we add B2CTenatB as Custom Identity provider inside B2CTenatA?
We have to use B2CTenatA users inside B2CTenatB tenant for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experimented with this by:

1. Creating an Azure AD B2C application in Tenant B that refers to the `https://my-tenant-a.b2clogin.com/my-tenant-a.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp` endpoint for Tenant A.
2. Creating [a custom OpenID Connect identity provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-oidc-idp) in Tenant A that refers to the `https://my-tenant-b.b2clogin.com/tfp/my-tenant-b.onmicrosoft.com/my-sign-up-sign-in-flow/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration` endpoint in Tenant B.

However, at runtime, after redirection from Tenant A to the sign-up and sign-in flow in Tenant B, Tenant B displays a `400 Bad Request` error.

I believe this is caused by the `state=StateProperties...` parameter that is passed from Tenant A to Tenant B.

So, unfortunately, it was a failed experiment.

Comment: Exactly i am getting the same error. can we override this issue?

Comment: Hi @Vetrivelmp. I don't believe so. I believe it's a bug issue. You might have to create [a support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-support) for it.

Comment: As of now one b2c tenant cannot be added as custom idp in another b2c tenant.